# jslots expansion

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery slot machine plugin and want to expand a bit, but am having trouble figuring out how it is working.

https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots

Currently, the demo uses it in a way that only one `<li>` is showing at a time. I want to expand that, so that you can see half of the the `<li>` above and half of the `<li>` below, kind of like a real slot machine, where you can see what is coming and what is leaving the visible area.

So, I expanded the container vertically, and I can see the `<li>`'s before and after BUT, weird things happen at the bottom, where the `<li>` disappears and then (I assume) gets appended to the top. It still happens if I make it 5+ `<li>`'s in the list. It also still happens if I increase the .slot size, but still constrain it with a shorter container height.

You will notice on this fiddle, when you click play, you will see the white background show through on the bottom. It gets worse as they slow down. Sometimes when they stop, it stops with the bottom part missing... I have attached the jslots.js file in the fiddle resources

http://jsfiddle.net/livinzlife/3bVe9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the CSS for the `li` elements:

```
margin-top: 72px;     /*half of the height */
margin-bottom: -72px; /*half of the height (negative)*/
```

so `.slot li` becomes:

```
.slot li{
    width: 190px;
    height: 144px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 72px;     /*half of the height */
    margin-bottom: -72px; /*half of the height (negative)*/
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To eliminate the background-color problem, add `background-color: yellow;` to the `jSlots-wrapper` class:

```
.jSlots-wrapper {  
    overflow: hidden; /* to hide the magic */  
    height: 296px; /* whatever the height of your list items are */  
    display: inline-block; /* to size width correctly, can use float too, or width*/  
    border: 1px solid #999;  
    position: absolute;
    width:570px;
    /*bottom: 130px;*/
    margin-top: 2em;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -285px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The principle of `background-color` holds true for images as well. Just set the `background-image` of the `.jSlots-wrapper` class to the image you're using for for the last `li` element and offset it vertically by (negative) half the `li` height

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bVe9/6/ for proof-of-concept (using images obtained by GIS for "random image" of size 256x256)

**UPDATE:**

Okay, change the CSS definition for `.slot li` from:

```
margin-top: 72px;     /*half of the height */
margin-bottom: -72px; /*half of the height (negative)*/
```

to:

```
margin-top: -72px;     /*half of the height (negative) */
margin-bottom: 72px;   /*half of the height*/
```

so `.slot li` becomes:

```
.slot li{
    width: 190px;
    height: 144px;
    margin-top: -72px;     /*half of the height (negative) */
    margin-bottom: 72px;   /*half of the height*/
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    background-size: 190px 144px;
}
```

and revert the CSS changes to the `.jSlots-wrapper` class definition and the problem is completely fixed (for both colors and images, here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bVe9/7/

This adjusts the slots so that the first `li` is offset upwards and the second `li` is the middle starting spot. Works perfectly on every click of the play button.

Comment: it did seem to help a bit, but the disappearing of the elements is still visible during animation. Even worse, if it stops on 1, the entire `<li>` is missing above it!

http://jsfiddle.net/livinzlife/3bVe9/3/

Comment: Updated answer with another CSS fix. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bVe9/5/

Comment: this is a little better again. The final use of this will include images though, so when an image disappears, and shows a solid background color, it will still flash. Ideally, there would be some way to have it shift the `<li>`'s from bottom to top behind the scenes, outside of the view of the container, so that there was never a time that the user visibly saw a `<li>` disappear

Comment: not too shabby for a css fix. Only remaining issue I find would be that when it slows down and relies on the background image (for the container), you can see that the image isn't moving. But, all things considered this is much better than where I started and a great effort for a css-only solution. So thanks!

Comment: The latest fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3bVe9/7/) fixed that problem by offsetting the `li` elements upwards instead of downwards (`li:nth-child(2)` is now the middle row when starting and `li:first-child` is only showing the bottom half of the image when starting). Oh, and happy to help! :)